# Task Manager never reports CPU usage above 51%, even when running CPU benchmark tools that should max out the CPU

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, cpu-usage, cpu-speed

My laptop (HP envy 15 x360 ar052na) never seems to be able to use more than 51% CPU usage, according to Task Manager. I've tried adjusting power plan settings but nothing seems to work. Even CPU benchmark tools never seem to be able to push my CPU usage beyond 51%.

Does anyone know a solution to allow my system to use 100% of its CPU power, or to get Task Manager to report correctly?

[image]

Comment: You are running Cinebench, which is a CPU/GPU benchmarking tool, which is using 45% of your CPU.  In order to free up your CPU for other tasks, you should stop running benchmarking tools in the background.

Comment: It is locked at 51% for all tasks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is obvious from the image included in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the answer? I'm more than happy to close this question myself if you could tell me.

Comment: @GilesTURNER - You are running a CPU intensive program, Cinebench, you should end that task.

Comment: The idea of that is that is locked at 51% for all tasks(whether that be games, video rendering etc,) and Cinebench was there just to show the lock

Comment: It cannot go any higher that 51% which worries me as I use this laptop for gaming and video editing and need that extra performance

Comment: The CPU usage is based on the current need.  If this happens when CPU intensive programs using 2 GB worth of memory are not running, then you need to provide a screenshot indicating that, instead of a case where 51% CPU usage would be expected, due to a single process taking 45% of your CPU.  You have not provided enough information about the problem or your system to explain the behavior other than the CPU usage in the screenshot is to be expected, edit your question with the required information to answer your question(which should be clarified because it currently is not clear).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xp9apt0 -A stress test which only stresses the CPU and this shows the system is locked at 51% usage.

Comment: From the original title and text it was unclear what problem OP was hoping to fix, but he's clarified that in the comments. I've edited the title and question to better reflect what it seems OP meant.